# Coda Slider Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2008, coda-slider

I am currently trying to implement Coda-Slider 3 into my website.

I have yet to do anything besides seeing if the slider would actually work and it is not working.

When it is loaded, I get the layout and everything but the slider wont slide and there is a broken image and a "loading..." text in the content area.

I am also getting an error in the status bar that is saying

"object doesnt support this property of method line:5"

here is my javascript / html

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS/coda-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/Stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slidertabs").codaSlider();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="coda-slider" id="slidertabs">
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Trial</h2>
            bambambasdfasf
            adfasf
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Trial 2</h2>
            la mambaafasdf
            asdfasfsa
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Source Code

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS/coda-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="CSS/Stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slidertabs").codaSlider();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="User.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQzMzc5MDEyMmRkIe8VCRe6PXi+FaNtf5wR5Ucxk58=" />
</div>

<div class="coda-slider" id="slidertabs">
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Trial</h2>
            bambambasdfasf
            adfasf
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Trial 2</h2>
            la mambaafasdf
            asdfasfsa
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/stz8U/ I stole the css and js for codaSlider from http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/. Maybe there is a problem in your css file.

Comment: always load jQuery before any other library that are dependant on it like jQuery UI.  Might/might not fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALWAYS load jQuery before any other library that are dependant on it like jQuery UI.

from http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/

> You also need to be sure you import the jQuery, jQuery UI, and the Coda Slider script files as well as the Coda Slider stylesheet. See below for detailed instructions and advanced options.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was the issue!

Comment: @user1512593 YW, Glad it fixed your issue :)